# XML file to ArrayList java using xstream error

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, xstream

i want to make convert xml file to Arraylist using xstream. when i make it i have error like below:

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: pattern : pattern
---- Debugging information ----
message             : pattern
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : pattern
class               : java.util.ArrayList
required-type       : java.util.ArrayList
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter
path                : /datas/data/pattern
line number         : 5
class[1]            : com.socket.server.ServerData$Datas
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             : 1.4.7
-------------------------------
```

here is my code

```
try{

        XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
        Datas datas = new Datas();
        File xmlx = new File("E:\\FileConfig.xml");

        xstream.alias("datas", Datas.class);
        xstream.alias("data", DataRegex.class);
        xstream.aliasField("pattern", DataRegex.class, "pattern");
        xstream.aliasField("destination", DataRegex.class, "destination");
        // xstream.addImplicitCollection(DataRegex.class, "data",Data.class);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
         List<DataRegex> dataz = (List<DataRegex>) xstream.fromXML(xmlx);
            System.out.println(dataz);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the error when check `List<DataRegex> dataz = (List<DataRegex>) xstream.fromXML(xmlx);` can anyone help. what i do?
this my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datas>

    <data>
        <patter>^[sS].*</pattern>
        <destination>C:\\Server\\s\\</destination>
    </data>

    <data>
        <pattern>^[dD].*</pattern>
        <destination>C:\\Server\\d\\</destination>
    </data>

</datas>
```

Comment: What does the XML file look like? The root element of any valid XML must be a single element, and it cannot be a list.

Comment: <datas>
 <data>
  <pattern>^[sS].*</pattern>
  <destination>C:\\Server\\s\\</destination>
 </data>

 <data>
  <pattern>^[dD].*</pattern>
  <destination>C:\\Server\\d\\</destination>
 </data>
</datas>   @Eng.Fouad

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: what do you mean ? @nitind

Comment: Not some debugging message, but the actual failure exception/error's stack trace.

Comment: the exception is same like the error  @nitind

Comment: What's the type for `DataRegex.pattern`?

Comment: @nitind is class

Answer (score 0):

The root element of any valid XML must be a single element, and it cannot be a list. As per your comment, `Datas` is the root element:

```
Datas dataz = (Datas) xstream.fromXML(xmlx);
```

Comment: i try it. and it same error. maybe you can help me how  make xml to arraylist